# Contour line data to DEM data

Tags: maps, tiles

I was just wondering if there was a way to use the free ordnance survey contour line data and generate DEM data using it. I’ve seen plenty of people converting DEM data to contour line data but not the other way around, could anyone help me out here?

I would also add more relevant tags to this question, though I do not have the reputation, nor do the tags exist

Answer (score 0):

OS Terrain 50 is available as ASCII grid as well as contours.  This OpenLayers example reads the unzipped ASCII files directly to produce a single zoom level EPSG:27700 tiled DEM (using the Mapbox RGB encoding method), but you could use similar logic in VB to create and save a PNG tile grid.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <style>
    html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .map {
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100% - 20px);
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.6.0/proj4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <div>
    <label>
      Elevation
      <span id="info">0.0</span> meters
    </label>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

      proj4.defs('EPSG:27700', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs ');

      ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = 200;
      canvas.height = 200;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imgData = ctx.createImageData(200, 200);

      var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
          projection: 'EPSG:27700',
          tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
            tileSize: 200,
            resolutions: [50],
            extent: [0, 0, 700000, 1300000],
            origin: [0, 0]
          }),
          crossOrigin: '',
          imageSmoothing: false,
          tileUrlFunction: function (tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) {
            var bounds = this.getTileGrid().getTileCoordExtent(tileCoord);
            var x = (Math.round(bounds[0]/10)/10) + 10000;
            var y = (Math.round(bounds[1]/10)/10) + 5000;
                var a1y = (4 - (Math.floor(y/5000)%5))*5;
                var a2y = (4 - (Math.floor(y/1000)%5))*5;
                var y1 = Math.floor(y/100)%10;
                a1y += (Math.floor(x/5000)%5);
                a2y += (Math.floor(x/1000)%5);
                var x1 = Math.floor(x/100)%10;
                var tile500km = String.fromCharCode(a1y + Math.floor((a1y+17)/25) + "A".charCodeAt(0));
                var tile100km = tile500km + String.fromCharCode(a2y + Math.floor((a2y+17)/25) + "A".charCodeAt(0));
                var tile10km = tile100km + x1 + y1;
            return 'https://mikenunn.net/data/terr50/grid/' + tile100km.toLowerCase() + '/' + tile10km + '.asc';
          },
          tileLoadFunction: function(tile, src) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.addEventListener('loadend', function (evt) {
              var data = this.response;
              if (data !== undefined) {
                var rows = data.split('\n');
                if (rows.length >= 205) {
                  for (var j = 0; j < 200; j++) {
                    var values = rows[j + 5].split(' ');
                    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                      var pixel = (parseFloat(values[i]) * 10) + 100000;
                      var index = (j * 200 + i) * 4;
                      imgData.data[index] = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
                      imgData.data[index+1] = (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
                      imgData.data[index+2] = (pixel >> 0) & 0xFF;
                      imgData.data[index+3] = 0xFF;
                    }
                  }
                  ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
                  tile.getImage().src = canvas.toDataURL();
                }
              } else {
                tile.setState(3);
              }
            });
            xhr.addEventListener('error', function () {
              tile.setState(3);
            });
            xhr.open('GET', src);
            xhr.send(); 
          }
        })
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [layer],
        view: new ol.View({
          projection: 'EPSG:27700',
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 51.5], 'EPSG:27700'),
          zoom: 14
        })
      });

      var showElevations = function(evt) {
        if (evt.dragging) {
          return;
        }
        map.forEachLayerAtPixel(
          evt.pixel,
          function(layer, pixel) {
            var height = -10000 + (pixel[0] * 256 * 256 + pixel[1] * 256 + pixel[2]) * 0.1;
            info.innerHTML = height.toFixed(1);
          },
          {
            layerFilter: function(candidate) {
              return layer === candidate;
            }
          }
        );
      };

      map.on('pointermove', showElevations);

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: See also https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/newsroom/blog/dynamic-hillshade-create-realistic-terrain-visualisations-using-os-open-zoomstack